# Converting List<Point2D.Double> to List<Point>

Tags: java

So, I need to call a method, which implements `scanLine`. It takes 3 arguments into parameter

1. rasterImage
2. List of Points
3. color

Another method returns a List of `Point2D.Double`. I pass the return value to new List:

```
ArrayList<Point2D.Double> outPolygon = clip.clipPolygon(cPoints, clipper);
```

Now I need to use the `outPolygon` list as an parameter of `scanLine`. However `Wrong argument type` pops out, because It needs List of `Point` and I am passing List of `Point2D.Double`.

How to convert it so I can pass it as an argument of `scanLine`?

I tried this:

```
// prevedení z PointDouble na PointInt 
for(int i=0; i<outPolygon.size(); i++)
{
    int x = (int)(outPolygon.get(i).x *(img.getWidth() - 1));
    int y = (int)((1 - outPolygon.get(i).y) * (img.getHeight() - 1));
    // uložení bodu do nového seznamu
    pointsInInteger.add(new Point(x,y));
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried this: `// převedení z PointDouble na PointInt
         for(int i=0; i<outPolygon.size(); i++){
          int x = (int)(outPolygon.get(i).x *(img.getWidth() - 1));
          int y = (int)((1 - outPolygon.get(i).y) * (img.getHeight() - 1));


          // uložení bodů do nového seznamu
          pointsInInteger.add(new Point(x,y));

         }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list containing a new Point2D.Double for each Point. Something like this would be an option.

```
List<Point> points = ...
List<Point2D.Double> points2s = points.stream()
    .map(point -> new Point2D.Double(point.getX(), point.getY()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or with a loop

```
    final List<Point2D.Double> list = new ArrayList<>(points.size());
    for (Point point : points) {
        Point2D.Double aDouble = new Point2D.Double(point.getX(), point.getY());
        list.add(aDouble);
    }
```

Comment: Incompatible types. Required ArrayList<Double> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to ArrayList<Double

Comment: If you're not familiar with Java 8 streams, I've added a classic loop example.

Comment: They needed to convert Point2D.Double to Point. Your answer is the wrong way around. Try just reversing the point types.